# wordpress and facebook: how this blog is done?

Tags: facebook, wordpress

Hello
I found a wordpress blog when people posts through facebook account:
http://www.puppetshow.fr/

Can someone tell me exactle what is the WP plugin to make such blog ?
I found MANY WP/facebook plugins but I need exactly this one.

(and what theme is used in this blog) ?

regards

Comment: we're not your puppies and this has no community interest.. mail the author.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be [this theme](http://www.wpexplorer.com/fast-blog-wordpress-theme.html). It's called Fastblog. And the Facebook comment form seems to be a plugin from Facebook itself; [Facebook social plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/).